# How to deploy a node.js project on my website?

Tags: node.js, server, ftp, network-solutions

I have a website with Network Solutions and I want to upload a node.js project. Network Solutions is not very user friendly with things like this so I cannot use my dashboard to do this.

How can I deploy a node.js project using an ftp connection, or is there a better way to do it on Network Solutions.

(My project uses a server.js file that I need to start.)

Also, would Network Solutions' cron jobs interface work for this?

Comment: Hi, having the same issue. I agree NS has some UI/UX hurtles to deal with. Did you get this figured out? Personally, I need to include a Mongo database from node.

Comment: I did not figure out a solution.

Comment: Sorry mods if this comment isn't appropriate or whatever. For those who see this in the future, perhaps avoid using Network Solutions altogether, there seem to be several different kinds of issues which make for a pretty frustrating experience IMO.